# Using google query to download parts of a published sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

This works:

```
curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/pub?gid=911257845&single=true&output=csv'
```

however I want to only pick up rows where count > 300.

The query before encoding would be

```
select * where F > 300
```

After encoding

```
select%20*%20where%20F%3E300
```

So the url becomes

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/pub?gid=911257845&output=csv&tq=select%20*%20where%20F%3E300
```

The line above works retrieves a file, but it returns the whole file, and doesn't filter.

Note that a published web sheet has the form

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/KEY/pub?gid=GID

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/pub?gid=911257845

This works. Adding &output=csv to it (no space before the &) works, and it downloads as a csv file.  This opens in excel and shows the data in the table.

I tried this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/pub?gid=911257845&output=csv&tq=select%20*%20where%20F%3E%20300

and

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/gviz/tq?gid=911257845&output=csv&tq=select%20*%20where%20F%3E300

and get errors -- resource not available.

The page above should be public for people who want to try.

This may be an issue between publishing a sheet, and sharing a whole spread sheet to anyone who has the link.

I've created a new page that uses importrange() that slurps up the page from the main sheet, and that one is public.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lqLuYJyHAKix-T8NR8wV8ZUUbVOJrZTysccid2-ycs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- When it uses query, please use like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### file ID ###/gviz/tq?gid=###&tq=### query ###`.
- When `select%20*%20where%20%F%3E300` is decoded, it is `select * where %F>300`.

  - `select * where F > 300` is `select%20%2a%20where%20F%20%3e%20300`.
- In order to output CSV, please use `tqx=out:csv`.
- Please share the Spreadsheet.

  - On Google Drive

    - On the Spreadsheet file
    - right-click -> Share -> Advanced -> Click "change" at "Private - Only you can access"
    - Check "On Anyone with the link"
    - Click "Save"
    - At "Link to share", copy URL.

      - Retrieve file ID from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### file ID ###/edit?usp=sharing`

#### Modified curl command :

```
curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### file ID ###/gviz/tq?gid=911257845&tq=select%20%2a%20where%20F%20%3e%20300&tqx=out:csv'
```

#### Reference :

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

The following 2 URLs are the comparison between your URL and my answer. The URL of my answer was matched to your URL.

#### 1. Your URL

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/gviz/tq?gid=911257845&output=csv&tq=select%20*%20where%20F%3E300
```

When above URL is separated,

1. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/`

   - `e/` is not required.
2. `2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc`

   - This is not the file ID of spreadsheet.
3. `/gviz/tq`
4. `gid=911257845`
5. `output=csv`
6. `tq=select%20*%20where%20F%3E300`

#### 2. In my answer matched to your URL

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### file ID ###/gviz/tq?gid=###&tqx=out:csv&tq=### query ###
```

When above URL is separated,

1. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/`
2. `### file ID ###`

   - You can see the detail of the file ID of spreadsheet at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id).
3. `/gviz/tq`
4. `gid=###`

   - You can use `gid=911257845`.
5. `tqx=out:csv`

   - This has to be used instead of `output=csv`.
6. `tq=### query ###`

   - You can use `tq=select%20*%20where%20F%3E300`.

#### Note :

- **Each number corresponds.**
- **And please share the Spreadsheet as follows. This is difference from "Publish to the web" on Spreadsheet.**

  - On Google Drive

    - On the Spreadsheet file
    - right-click -> Share -> Advanced -> Click "change" at "Private - Only you can access"
    - Check "On Anyone with the link"
    - Click "Save"
    - At "Link to share", copy URL.

      - Retrieve file ID from ``https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###

Comment: The %F allows it to at least return, but it doesn't filter anything.

Comment: @Sherwood Botsford  I'm sorry for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. I saw your updated question. There is a problem for your URL. The URL for using the query of ``tq`` is like ``https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### file ID ###/gviz/tq?gid=###&tq=### query ###``. Please use file ID of Spreadsheet. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: How does my last version differ from yours.  The sheet is public.  Anyone with link can view.  Two sheets are published.  without a gid= the first one comes up. I tried putting the &output=csv at the end.  Still didn't work.

Comment: @Sherwood Botsford I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. The URL you use is not file ID. So we cannot test. I'm sorry.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/pub

Comment: Works with the final one. above.

Comment: @Sherwood Botsford Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your problem was solved.