# Specify target worksheet in structured query of Google Sheets data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-query-language

I am trying to query data from one of my google spreadsheets, and I have read [the docs here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#setting-the-query-in-the-data-source-url).

My spreadsheet has two tabs/sheets. I can query data from the first sheet, but I can't figure out how to query data from the second sheet.

My query url looks like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SpreadSheetId]/gviz/tq?tq=[query]
```

If I open the sheet in a browser I can see the sheet Id in the browser url:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SpreadSheetId]/edit#gid=[SheetId]
```

Is there any way to specify this sheetId in the query url? I have tried adding various versions of `/#gid=[sheetId]` to my query url but it returns the full html of the page, not the json I expect.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511747/using-google-query-to-download-parts-of-a-published-sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[spreadSheetId]/gviz/tq?gid=[sheetId]&tq=[query]
```

Credits to tehhowch for pointing me in the right direction!