# How do I get a someone else's Google Spreadsheet to my Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe, google-sheets

I have an Open-Source Live Data, but it's in the format of Google Spreadsheet and not CSV or JSON. How do I get this Live Spreadsheet's data in my Pandas Data Frame?

[HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#) is the link to that Open Source Live Spreadsheet.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve the values from the Web published Google Spreadsheet.

  - The URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/###/pubhtml#`.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the dataframe.
- You want to achieve this using Python.

In this answer, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Modify the endpoint. By this modification, the values can be retrieved as the CSV data.

   - From: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/###/pubhtml#`
   - To: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/###/pub?output=csv`
2. Retrieve the values from the modified endpoint as the CSV data.
3. Put the CSV data to the dataframe.

#### Sample script:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pub?output=csv'
res = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(res.content), sep=',')
```

#### Reference:

- [Using google query to download parts of a published sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48511747/7108653)